# When using imacros, I need to assign text into a field on a webpage: TEST_contentDiv="Books and Videos"

Tags: imacros

When Imacros hits this section of code that uses a rich text editor on a webpage, Imacros quits recording (in any mode, using EVENT or the old way).

```
<div id="TEST_contentDiv" class="reContentArea reContentAreaToggle" title="Rich text editor with ID TEST" style="position: relative; height: 188px;" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

I want to assign the data (Books and Videos) to the field TEST_contentDiv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to play something like this:

```
SET text "Books and Videos"
EVENTS TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="#TEST_contentDiv" CHARS={{text}}
```